# Append multiple list instances into a single instance

Tags: java, spring

In the code below I want to fetch vaccines eligible for people added by a user currently logged in.

For the first pupil I get the list of vaccines correctly, but for the second, the list of vaccines I get overrides the previous list.

How can I modify the code so that the `vaccines`  instance contains the complete list of vaccines.

```
for (People p : p1)
{
    Date dt1=p.getDob();

    Date date = new Date();
    long diff=date.getTime() - dt1.getTime();
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    double age = (double) diffDays/365;

    vaccines=vaccineDao.getVaccine(age);

}

 models.put( "myVaccines", vaccines);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<Vaccine> allVaccines = new ArrayList<>();
for (People p : p1)
{
    Date dt1=p.getDob();

    Date date = new Date();
    long diff=date.getTime() - dt1.getTime();
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    double age = (double) diffDays/365;

    List vaccines=vaccineDao.getVaccine(age);
    allVaccines.addAll(vaccines);

}

 models.put( "myVaccines", allVaccines);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `vaccines` is an instance of a `List`, `Collection` etc. and `vaccineDao.getVaccine()` also returns a collection, you can do something like

```
vaccines.addAll(vaccineDao.getVaccine())
```

If `vaccineDao.getVaccine()` returns a single element, then do

```
vaccines.add(vaccineDao.getVaccine())
```